# oracle query taking more execution time in oracle when i m using AND condition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

This below query taking more execution time when in filtering with AND Condition TD.A97 = '4408' ,and apart from them I m joining two table and two synonyms can u help me to reduce execution time  for this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TC.CUS_ACNT_NBR ,
                TC.CUS_ACNT_ROLE_CD ,
                TD.F_DOCNUMBER,
                TD.A45,
                HD.SHPMNT_NBR, 
                HD.SHPMNT_ID 
FROM   TDOC_CUS_ACNT TC
       INNER JOIN TDOC TD ON TD.F_DOCNUMBER = TC.F_DOCNUMBER 
       INNER JOIN DWH_SHIPMENT_DIM HD ON TD.A45 = HD.SHPMNT_NBR
       INNER JOIN DWH_INVOICE_CHARGE_FACT ICF ON HD.shpmnt_dim_key = ICF.shipment_dim_fk
WHERE  TC.CUS_ACNT_ROLE_CD in ('BILL','SHPR','THRD') 
AND    TD.A97 = '4408' ;
```

Comment: Just by looking at it? See if index on TD.A97 column helps. Otherwise, provide explain plan.

Comment: If you show us the execution plans with and without the AND, we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can use to reduce execution time is to use parallel hints in your query.

```
 ALTER TABLE  T PARALLEL 4;

 SELECT  /*+ parallel(4) */    DISTINCT TC.CUS_ACNT_NBR ...
```

[oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm)

Comment: Please let me know how to use parallel hints in my query, I m using same way but its not working.

Comment: Just add the `/*+ parallel */` hint after your select statement. this does not improve your query but makes oracle to take advantage of your physical resource. therefore your query will be distributed to run in parallel

Answer (score 0):

explain plan:below my explain plan with with AND condition.

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

Plan hash value: 53520552

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | TQ/Ins |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                     |  1639K|   148M|       | 15382   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                   |                     |       |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)             | :TQ10007            |  1639K|   148M|       | 15382   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,07 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE                    |                     |  1639K|   148M|   164M| 15382   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,07 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                    |                     |  1639K|   148M|       | 15382   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,07 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH                 | :TQ10006            |  1639K|   148M|       | 15382   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | P->P | HASH       |
|   6 |       HASH UNIQUE                 |                     |  1639K|   148M|   164M| 15382   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN                  |                     |  1639K|   148M|       | 12902   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         PX RECEIVE                |                     |   434K|    33M|       |  8351   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          PX SEND HASH             | :TQ10005            |   434K|    33M|       |  8351   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 10 |           HASH JOIN BUFFERED      |                     |   434K|    33M|       |  8351   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            BUFFER SORT            |                     |       |       |       |            |          |  Q1,05 | PCWC |            |
|  12 |             PX RECEIVE            |                     |   325K|  7636K|       |  2335   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |              PX SEND HASH         | :TQ10001            |   325K|  7636K|       |  2335   (1)| 00:00:01 |        | S->P | HASH       |
|* 14 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TDOC_CUS_ACNT       |   325K|  7636K|       |  2335   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|  15 |            PX RECEIVE             |                     |   272K|    15M|       |  6015   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |             PX SEND HASH          | :TQ10004            |   272K|    15M|       |  6015   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 17 |              HASH JOIN            |                     |   272K|    15M|       |  6015   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  18 |               PX RECEIVE          |                     |   268K|  5508K|       |   660   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  19 |                PX SEND HASH       | :TQ10003            |   268K|  5508K|       |   660   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | P->P | HASH       |
|  20 |                 PX BLOCK ITERATOR |                     |   268K|  5508K|       |   660   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
|* 21 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TDOC                |   268K|  5508K|       |   660   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  22 |               BUFFER SORT         |                     |       |       |       |            |          |  Q1,04 | PCWC |            |
|  23 |                PX RECEIVE         |                     |  1769K|    62M|       |  5354   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  24 |                 PX SEND HASH      | :TQ10000            |  1769K|    62M|       |  5354   (1)| 00:00:01 |        | S->P | HASH       |
|  25 |                  REMOTE           | SHIPMENT_DIM        |  1769K|    62M|       |  5354   (1)| 00:00:01 |   TDIM | R->S |            |
|  26 |         BUFFER SORT               |                     |       |       |       |            |          |  Q1,06 | PCWC |            |
|  27 |          PX RECEIVE               |                     |  6677K|    82M|       |  4550   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|  28 |           PX SEND HASH            | :TQ10002            |  6677K|    82M|       |  4550   (1)| 00:00:01 |        | S->P | HASH       |
|  29 |            REMOTE                 | INVOICE_CHARGE_FACT |  6677K|    82M|       |  4550   (1)| 00:00:01 |   TDIM | R->S |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("HD"."SHPMNT_DIM_KEY"="ICF"."SHIPMENT_DIM_FK")
  10 - access("TD"."F_DOCNUMBER"="TC"."F_DOCNUMBER")
  14 - filter("TC"."CUS_ACNT_ROLE_CD"='BILL' OR "TC"."CUS_ACNT_ROLE_CD"='SHPR' OR "TC"."CUS_ACNT_ROLE_CD"='THRD')
  17 - access("TD"."A45"="HD"."SHPMNT_NBR")
  21 - filter("TD"."A45" IS NOT NULL AND "TD"."A97"='4408')

Remote SQL Information (identified by operation id):
----------------------------------------------------

  25 - SELECT "SHPMNT_DIM_KEY","SHPMNT_NBR","SHPMNT_ID" FROM "DIM"."SHIPMENT_DIM" "HD" (accessing 'TDIM.WORLD' )

  29 - SELECT "SHIPMENT_DIM_FK" FROM "DIM"."INVOICE_CHARGE_FACT" "ICF" (accessing 'TDIM.WORLD' )


Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=5)
   - Degree of Parallelism is 16 because of table property
```